# List Top Items *and* Whether Purchased (one SQL query)

Tags: sql, sql-server

Here are the key fields I'm working with: (They come from a join on two other tables and there are also some extra fields like date I'll be filtering on, but that stuff I can handle.)

Customer Type (text), Item ID (number), Sales $s (number), Customer ID (number)

I want to answer two questions with one query, if possible:

1) For a given list of customer type(s), what were the top 25 items (by sum of sales)

2) Using the list of 25 items generated in step 1, did a given list of customer IDs purchase each of the specified items?

So my final result would look something like this:

```
(header) Item #    | Customer Purchased?
(row 01) Item 1123 | Yes
(row 02) Item 2452 | Yes
(row 03) Item 3354 | No
...
(row 25) Item 2554 | No
```

The item numbers would be listed in decreasing sales volume (within the specified customer category/categories) and I'd be testing whether sum of sales > 0 to trip the Yes / No flag on customer(s) purchased.

Thanks!

Comment: What SQL engine are you using? SQL Server, MySql, other?

Comment: I'm using SQL Server.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have your columns in a table #Orders, and the "list of customer Ids" in a table #CustomerIds:

```
create table #Orders (CustomerId int, CustomerType varchar(10), ItemId int, Sales decimal);
create table #MyCustomers (CustomerId int);
```

... you could try something like this:

```
declare @CustomerType varchar(10) = 'Ugly';

with MarkedOrders as (
  select
    o.ItemId,
    o.Sales,
    case when mc.CustomerId is not null then 1 else 0 end IsMyCustomer
  from 
    Orders o
    left join #MyCustomers mc
      on mc.CustomerId = o.CustomerId
  where
    o.CustomerType = @CustomerType
)
select top 25
  o.ItemId,
  max(IsMyCustomer) IsPurchasedByMyCustomer
from MarkedOrders o
group by o.ItemId
order by sum(o.Sales) desc
```